# RabbitMq java how to decrease throughput

Tags: java, rabbitmq, throughput

I have a service, which receive messages via queu rabbitmq and then sends it via rest to another system. The external system have some limitations (for example 50 messages per seconds). So, I need to set this limitation on our service side (if it is possible on rabbitmq side)
I have only one idea to store messages in database, and before receiving from queue compare it with throughput and if it is greater send it to queue again.
Probably someone solve similar task - would be helpfull. Thanks!